# What will be the alternate of win32api for Linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, system

I have a Ruby code for a site response. To check if the site is UP Or Down. But it works only for windows.If i want to use it for Ubuntu what will be the change ? I am trying to run this but win32api line getting an error on Ubuntu.

```js
require "net/https"
require "uri"
require "Win32API"
uri = URI.parse("https://address ")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = http.request(request)
test = response.body
delay = 10
message = "Site is OK"
title = "Up"
api = Win32API.new('user32', 'MessageBox',['L', 'P', 'P', 'L'],'I')
until !test.include? "false"
time = Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
puts time
puts "Down"
response = http.request(request)
test = response.body
sleep(delay)
end
api.call(0,message,title,0)
until test.include? "false"
api.call(0,message,title,0)
time = Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
puts time
puts "Up"
response = http.request(request)
test = response.body
sleep(delay)
end
```

Comment: If you don't need the message boxes, just delete the `api` and `Win32Api` stuff. If you need this, you have to use a different GUI framework.

Comment: @HolgerJust.. Thanks ... its now working ....